# Ferries route planner?

Tags: planning, ferries, routes, itineraries

I'm currently in Sofia, Bulgaria, and I'd love to move to Lisbon for the summer, at the beginning of July. Problem is...it's a 3500 kilometres route, and as much as I like to ride my motorbike this is gonna be a bit too much, both economically and from a time point of view: as I'm literally moving, it's hard to drive the bike full loaded for more than 500 kilometres a day.

I'm thinking about shortening the route a bit by taking some ferry (not directly from Sofia, ok :-D ) to Spain, maybe crossing Italy, but it seems too complicate to plan by hand, there are too many options.

So the question is: does anyone know about some site that allows to build a route using ferries, giving out the full total cost for various options?

Comment: Rome2Rio can easily do it.

Comment: A better bet is ferrylines.com, which lists all routes, as well as linking to all operators on a given route so you can check fares on their websites

Comment: To both: they sounds like answers, and good answers too, so why are comments instead? ;-)

Comment: @Crazydre that's an answer, my friend.. add it and I'll upvote, and included Rome2Rio with a nod to JonathanReez

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the [ferrylines.com](http://www.ferrylines.com) map, the quickest Option by far is to cycle to Durrës in Albania, then take a ferry to Ancona in Italy, then cycle to Civitavecchia, then catch a Ferry to Barcelona and finally cycle to Portugal